# How Kafka schedule the producers and consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am studying the internals of Apache Kafka; how it works.

The Kafka brokers deal with the requests from the multiple producers and consumers.

I want to know how Kafka schedules those requests. (i.e. FCFS)
 - Is it First-Come-First-Served (FCFS) or Processor Sharing (PS) ?
 - Does the producers have the higher priorities than consumers?

The Kafka official documentation does not have explanation on it.
Can anyone give me an idea on this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a TCP connection per client at the broker (the client can either be a consumer or producer or any number of producers &/or consumers)
The way CPU resources are shared between different connections is not a property controlled by Kafka. This depends on the OS on which your broker is running. Specifically, the scheduler implementation of your OS (which decide how processes are schedules on cores), will decide this.
If the scheduler is FCFS, this will very well be FCFS. More generally, the scheduler implementation in most OS is some version of Multi Level Feedback Queue.

Thus, this has got nothing to do with Kafka.

Comment: If you know, could you guide me to the implementation code that decides to rely on OS scheduler? How Kafka delegate it to OS scheduler?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Kafka... the whole code "delegates to the OS".